# Advanced depth visualisation Intel Realsense camera in python

Tags: python, realsense

I want to modify the advanced depth visualisation parameters of my Intel Realsense D405 camera in python using the pyrealsense2 library.

I am currently able to modify these parameters in the realsense-viewer application:

[image: Realsense camera depth visualisation parameters]

I am able to export this to a json file. I would assume I can import these settings in python somehow and get the depth visualisation I desire but I can´t figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `librealsense` package has an example for using the advanced parameters, which include the advanced depth parameters you're looking for:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/examples/python-rs400-advanced-mode-example.py
More specifically to your question, the object returned from `rs.rs400_advanced_mode(dev)` (line 28 in the example) has a `load_json` method which you could use to load the exported settings into your code.

Comment: I ran the script in that example and it just returned this:  
`No D400 product line device that supports advanced mode was found`.  
I looked up my device product ID, which is 0B5B. This is not in the list of product id's specified at the beginning of the script:  
`DS5_product_ids = ["0AD1", "0AD2", "0AD3", "0AD4", "0AD5", "0AF6", "0AFE", "0AFF", "0B00", "0B01", "0B03", "0B07", "0B3A", "0B5C"]`.  
Is there any chance there is some other way to get around this?

Comment: Update: I just removed the first control of the script where it checks for the camera support and it worked like a charm. I am guessing the example on GitHub is outdated since the Realsense D405 camera came out in April 2022 while the script was last edited on 08/02/2021. Thank you!